# "CREATE SCHEMA foo ..." query from C extension in PostgreSQL (using SPI_execute_with_args)

Tags: c, database, postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-extensions

I'm trying to execute a SQL query from a C extension built for PostgreSQL, using the Server Programming Interface (SPI). The query should create a new schema with quite a large number of tables. (Basically it should setup a workspace for users to work in.) But since the user should be able to create multiple workspaces, I don't know the schema name when writing the script. So I need a way to supply this at runtime. But I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to do this by using `SPI_execute_with_args` as the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/spi-spi-execute-with-args.html) states the following:

> `SPI_execute_with_args` executes a command that might include references
>   to externally supplied parameters. The command text refers to a
>   parameter as `$n`, and the call specifies data types and values for each
>   such symbol. `read_only` and `count` have the same interpretation as in
>   `SPI_execute`.
>
> The main advantage of this routine compared to `SPI_execute` is that
>   data values can be inserted into the command without tedious
>   quoting/escaping, and thus with much less risk of SQL-injection
>   attacks.

The SQL script looks like the following (If I replace the `$1` with a real schema name manually and run it as a normal script, everything works as it should):

```
CREATE SCHEMA $1;
ALTER SCHEMA $1 OWNER TO some_user;

CREATE FUNCTION $1.foo() ...

CREATE TABLE $1.bar ...
...
```

But now I want to run it from the C code, and as the documentation lacks any working examples on SPI, I had to google around to find anything that could guide me further. And I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985956/postgresql-c-function-suggestion) on SO where the function looks like this:

> ```
> ...
>
> Datum 
> foo(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
> {
>     int ret;
>     Datum args[1];
>     Oid argtypes[1] = { INT4OID };
>     Datum result;
>     bool isnull;
>
>     SPI_connect();
>
>     args[0] = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
>
>     /* ensure expected result type by casting */
>     ret = SPI_execute_with_args("SELECT ($1 + 10)::int", 
>                                    1, argtypes, args, NULL,
>                                    true, 1);
>
>     Assert(SPI_processed == 1);
>
>     result = SPI_getbinval(SPI_tuptable->vals[0], SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isnull);
>     Assert(!isnull);
>
>     SPI_finish();
>
>     PG_RETURN_DATUM(result);
> }
>
> ...
> ```

This works as it should (replaces `$1` with a number entered as a parameter).

But as soon I start to modify it to work with my own query, everything breaks. I can't even make it work with only the first line of the query.

I have, for the record, also tried to just run a simple `SELECT '$1'` query and replace it with various variables. But nothing else than the example works. Either the server crashes, returns invalid syntax at `$1` or just returns `$1` as the answer.

---

If I'm right it seems like it matters **where** and **what** you want to replace `$1` **with**. And that SPI doesn't just do a "find and replace" on the `$1`?

I have tried some different OID:s when testing various variable types, like: `ANYOID`, `CSTRINGOID`, `CHAROID`, `REGNAMESPACEOID`, `TEXTOID` etc. And I have tried to both send the variable as a pure char array and as a pointer to a text block allocated with `SPI_palloc()` or `palloc()`. But no success...

Example code that I've put together from the examples and documentation I've found:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(foobar);
Datum foobar(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Datum arguments[1];
    Oid argument_types[1] = { ANYOID };
    Datum result;
    bool isnull;
    arguments[0] = "some_text";

    SPI_connect();
    SPI_execute_with_args("SELECT '$1'", 1, argument_types, arguments, NULL, false, 0);
    result = SPI_getbinval(SPI_tuptable->vals[0], SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isnull);
    SPI_finish();

    PG_RETURN_DATUM(result);
}
```

When running this code I get the following result:

```
SELECT foobar();
 foobar
--------
 $1
(1 row)
```

---

*I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this, but even if it isn't, it would be nice to know more of how this SPI function works as I will need it further into the project.*

Does anybody have any working examples to this or something to push me into the right direction?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So I've added an example of my own code and what it results in. Is there anything else that I should add/remove to make my question easier to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$1` in your `SELECT '$1'` is inside single quotes, so it is a string literal and not a parameter.

Use the following instead:

```
SELECT $1
```

Note that you can use a parameter where you could also use a literal of the same type, but you cannot use a parameter for an identifier like a table or column name.

If you need a variable in such a place, you'll have to construct a query string using `snprintf`.

To avoid SQL injection, use `quote_identifier` from `utils/builtins.h`.

---

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```c
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(foobar);
Datum foobar(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{   
    Datum arguments[1];
    Oid argument_types[1] = { TEXTOID };
    char *res;
    bool isnull;
    Datum result;
    /* for when we don't want to use the SPI context */
    MemoryContext context = CurrentMemoryContext;

    arguments[0] = CStringGetTextDatum("some_text");

    SPI_connect();

    SPI_execute_with_args("SELECT $1", 1, argument_types, arguments, NULL, false, 0); 

    result = SPI_getbinval(SPI_tuptable->vals[0], SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isnull);

    res = MemoryContextStrdup(context, TextDatumGetCString(result));

    SPI_finish();

    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(CStringGetTextDatum(res));
}
```

Comment: When I remove the single quotes from the `SELECT $1` the server crashes with the following response:

`server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.`

Comment: The main reason for me to do this in C is that I will have a lot of other code that will require C. And I thought that it would be best to have everything in 1 place. And that it is pre-compiled, which is a pro for speed. In this case however it will probably not do that much for speed as it is just a usual query being run.

Comment: Alright, I was playing around a bit and tried with `CSTRINGOID` instead of `ANYOID`. Which resulted in:"ome_text" and if I try with different strings it always removes the first character. Any clue why?

Comment: Ok, I have added a running version of your code to the answer. You'd also need to check the return codes!